# How to correctly copy `Texture2D` to another adapter?

Tags: direct3d11

I have a `Texture2D` that I received from a different app using `device.OpenSharedResource`. I need to make a copy of that texture on another **adapter**, which has some capabilities that the originator adapter does not.

This is what I am currently trying to do:

```cs
var desc = tex.Description;
var copy = new Texture2D(device, desc);
tex.Device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(src: tex, dst: copy);
```

This is what the description looks like:
[image]

As you can see this generates an access violation exception. This makes me think I need to modify the description of the target texture. But in what way?

If that matters, as I don't have the real hardware, my target device for testing is WARP (e.g. `DriverType.Warp` or `D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP`). I assume it should be possible to copy a texture to a WARP device just like if it were a real GPU.

P.S. I also tried to directly use `OpenSharedResource` on the target device, but it simply returns `INVALID_ARG` (that happens on both NVidia GPU and WARP).